# Calculate big O

Tags: big-o

So I want to calculate the Big O for this snippet of code, but I am unsure of how to approach it. Some help to get started would be appreciated.

`

```
            for ( i = 1 ; i * i < n ; i++){
                for ( j = 1 ; j < n ; j++)
                {
                  ...
                }
            }
            for ( i = 1 ; i < n ; i++){
                for ( j = i % 5 ; i + j < 2000; j++)
                {
                  ...
                }
```

`

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: Here's a massive post regarding Big O notation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: First inner loop is O(n), outer loop O(sqrt(n)), which means O(n*log n). Second loop... I'll have to say O(n) since when n goes to infinity, the inner loop goes to constant, but it's been a while since I took math, so take it with a grain of salt ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so we start at the first inner loop, and see that it is `O(n)`. Then, `i` goes from 1 to square root n, so the complexity for that loop is `O(sqrt(n))`. We then multiply them to find the complexity for the first nested loop, which is `O(n * sqrt(n))`.

The second outer loop has complexity `n`, and the inner loop runs a defined number of times (not dependent on n), so the total complexity is `O(n * sqrt(n) + n)`.

Comment: To note then, `O(n*sqrt(n)+n)` is the same as `O(n*log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

Big O is the worst case scenario and in this case is N^2 because you have a nested for loop inside of the first for loop.

The second set of for loops is only big O of N because the inner for loop will run at most of 2000 times and that in the scope of things is very minor, especially when N is huge.